# Read the entire Excel file in atom format using Excel Services

Tags: 2010, excel, excel-services

I am trying to read Excel file stored in Document Library using Excel Services. I need to fetch the entire workbook content in a single request call. I have tried using `Ranges` using it like

```
http://<SERVER>/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/<LIBRARY>/<FILE>/model/Ranges('B8|K60')?$format=atom
```

Bt there I have to specify the table name/range from which I need to fetch the data. The Excel file is generated by third party source and has varying number of rows.

The closest I was able to find REST API

```
http://<SERVER>/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/<LIBRARY>/<FILE>/model/?$format=workbook
```

which returns the entire Excel file in binary format, but not in atom format.

Is there a REST API which gets the entire content of at least the first worksheet from the Excel file in ATOM format? Is there any efficient way to read all the rows in Excel file using Excel Services in a single (or less) REST API call?

Comment: Can't you use 'Range(Cells.Address)' or 'Range("A1").CurrentRegion' inside Ranges of the 1st api call?

Comment: @TaranGoel: No. I think you are confusing this with VB code. This is a URL so I cannot use `Cells.Address` or `CurrentRegion`.

Comment: I haven't work on it but thought maybe it'll work..:)